# React utility function to bind this keyword

Tags: reactjs, this, es6-modules

I have a utility function, but `this` is undefined even I bind it in my react component:

`/util/index:`

```
export const handleKeyPress = e =>{
  console.log(this)
}
```

`/component/input/:`

```
import {handleKeyPress}  from "../util/index"
class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        isOpen: false
    }
  }
  this.handleKeyPress = handleKeyPress.bind(this)

  render(){
   return <input onKeyPress = {this.handleKeyPress} />
 }
}
```

So on my input keypress, `this` is undefined in the function even I bind it inside my constructor.  What can I do?

Comment: wondering why there's need for `this` inside the util function

Comment: So I can make it reuseable in other similar components

Comment: export const handleKeyPress = e =>{ console.log(this) } //  // by `this` you mean the `Input` class?

Comment: yes, let say I want to change the state `isOpen` with the util function, but the util function doesn't recognize `this.state`.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to writing bind in the constructor, you can write your event with arrow function.

```
render()
return <input onKeyPress = {() => 
this.handleOnKeyPress() }/>
 }
```

After that you can delete your binding code line of component.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import { handleKeyPress } from "../util/index"
    class Input extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          isOpen: false
        }
      }

      render() {
        return <input onKeyPress={(e) => handleKeyPress(e)} />
      }
    }
```

remove this from calling function and remove bind function line